# getting value from delete update button on dynamic html table. php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing a webpage with a table that's populated dynamically when the page is loaded. i have a delete/update buttons on each row of the table, but i cant figure out how to get the value (message id) of the selected table row so i can run the delete/edit script on the correct record.

this is the code that populates the table:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_post)){
       $post_date=$row['msg_post_date'];
       $post_title=$row['msg_title'];
       $post_id=$row['msg_id'];
       $post_list[]=$row['msg_id'];

       //table post date
       echo "<td><div class='thumbnail-mar-less'>$post_date</div></td>";

       //table title
       echo "<td><div class='thumbnail-mar-less'><a href='#'>$post_title</a></div></td>";

       //table buttons
       echo "<td>
       <form class='form-inline thumbnail-mar-less' role='form'>
         <div class='form-group'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>Edit Post</button></div>
         <div class='form-group'><button name='delete'value=' ' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Delete</button></div>
         </div>
        </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

any suggestions on how i would assign and retrieve a value to each row???

Comment: Use $row['msg_id'] for the value of the delete button?

Comment: You could also add a hidden field containing the field's ID to the form, e.g. `<input type="hidden" value="$post_id" />`

Comment: Iv tried both of the suggested.. problem is that the value of any variable is the value of the last record/row in the table. I need it to somehow get the currant value of the selected html table row from the button.  I'm thinking maybe an array, by how would I reference the correct value after it has been populated?

Answer (score 0):

You form has no "action", so it will submit to the "current" url automatically.
If the current url is the same page as your form handling PHP then that's okay.
Your form has no closing tag, so, the rest may look strange on the page.

as bobdye and Simon MᶜKenzie pointed out, you should have a field in the form that contains the `$post_id` value.

try something like this:

```
echo '
        <form class="some fancy classes" action="some_handler.php">
            <input type="hidden" value="'.$post_id.'">
            <input type="submit" value="go!">
        </form>
     ';
```